# как обратиться к html из content_script

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

как вытащить из html-шаблона, находящегося в папке расширения, текст или элемент, и вставить его в сайт?

этот код из документации, и почему-то не работает:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange; // Implemented elsewhere.
xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/templates/index.html'), true);
xhr.send();

function handleStateChange() {
    console.log(xhr.status) // 0
    console.log(xhr.responseText) // ""
  }
```

возвращается пустая строка

Comment: Что в этом коде "не работает"?

Comment: _chrome.extension.getURL('/templates/index.html')_
_chrome.runtime.getURL('/templates/index.html')_ -- тоже не. они возвращают такой путь:
_"chrome-extension://ecomfilbpgbhmlckbpbjclofmjmjdibm/templates/button.html"_

Comment: елки-палки, никто не знает. вот же вы невежды! :3
"chrome-extension://ecomfilbpgbhmlckbpbjclofmjmjdibm/templates/index.html" -- в комментарии выше написано неправильно.